# Laravel 4: Multiple Tenant Application, each tenant it's own database and one global database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Currently i have a application that hosts multiple tenants written in CodeIgniter.
But i am really loving Laravel 4 and i would like to start migrating the application to Laravel.

Here is the current setup:

- Each tenant has it's own database.
- There is just one set of application files.
- When we create a new tenant a new database is created and an install script is run and the database is seeded with some initial information.
- Each tenant also has it's own subdomain. That is how we can detect which database to use.
- There is a main database that holds tenant information and users and some other general tables.
- When a schema update is needed we just create an update script that will run for each tenant. This happens via a specially coded CLI script for Codeigniter

In Codeigniter it's relatively easy to start and end new database connections.

With Laravel i have the following issues/questions.

- How would you start/end database connections on the fly?
- I would like to use Migrations but i would like to run them for each tenant. Migrations currently only run on the "main" database connection. And it only runs once.
- Same goes for seeding..

These are my main issues, i have some other minor stuff but those can be worked around.

Hopefully someone can shed some light..

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm just taking a stab at this, so be warned :) 
The DatabaseManager class, which is used whenever you call DB, has and extend method. Here's the [link to the source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/DatabaseManager.php#L160). The DB::connection() method should return an instance of [Illuminate\Database\Connection](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php#L95). From all this, I would create a new user connection as follows:

```
$user = Auth::user();
DB::extend($user->username, function() use ($user) {
   // $pdo = new PDO(); set this up how you see fit
    return new Illuminate\Database\Connection($pdo, $user->databaseName, $tablePrefix);
});
```

Personally, I would add a new method to each user, User::databaseConnection(), and call that when I extend the DatabaseManager.

```
DB::extend($user->username, function() use ($user) {
    return $user->databaseConnection();
});
```

Through out your application you should be able to call a registered user's connection via:

```
DB::connection(Auth::user()->username);
```

**Update**

Depending on how often and when you'd be calling the tenant connection, you may want to use the IOC container.

```
App::bind('tenantDB', function()
{
     return DB::connection(Auth::user()->username);
});

App::make('tenantDB')->insert(...);
```

I forgot about migrations and seeding. For migrations, you can set the file path

```
php artisan migrate:make foo --path=app/migrations
```

So if you use the Config class to set the default database or DB::setDefaultConnection($username), I'd assume all migrations and seeding will be done for the current connection. When that process if complete you can switch back to you main database.

**Update 2**

The laravel developers are amazing and I should have definitely got the urge to check this out sooner than later. You can do migrations and seed on any database connection you've created.

```
artisan migrate --database='userConnectionName' 
artisan db:seed --database='userConnectionName'
```

Looking at Barry's answer, that is probably a good deal simpler than extending the DatabaseManager.

If you want to see all the options for these commands just run:

```
artisan help migrate
artisan help db:seed
```

Comment: That is a pretty nice solution. Can you clarify one thing for me? 
How would each migration run for each tenant? Like i said there is a just one set of application files and tenants are not hardcoded in any way. All tenants must run the current version of the application so they also have migrate accordingly.

Comment: So I think I just found you a better solution. The migrate command does have a database option so `php artisan migrate --database='userConnectionName'` should work. For the seeding, you may still have to change the default connection. I'd say you have a couple options though: (1) write a custom command that does the seeding or (2) put in a feature request for a --database option for the seeding command.

Comment: so scratch my last comment about seeding. the seeding also has a --database option. `artisan db:seed --database='userConnectionName'`. These laravel developers are awesome!

Comment: I know about that option but that means that the database connection must be hardcoded in the config file. The only easy solution i found was to create a new task which will loop through all the tenants and change the default connection to that tenant's DB. Same goes for seeding.

Comment: I've got migrations and seeding working on multiple databases using Barry's idea. I created a connection named 'test' and ran artisan: `artisan migrate --seed  --database=tenant`. Creating a 'tenant' connection and then changing the options via Config::set() looks like the cleanest way to accomplish what you're after. To ensure a specific tenant database is being used by artisan, add code to set/verify the connection options to the start/artisan.php file.

Comment: Im new to Redis, my question is if I choose this approach I should a have a cluster for each tenant or a default one for the entire app?

Answer (score 6):

You can create 1 database with the tenant database credentials, and dynamically set them in your app:

```
$tenant = Tenant::where('username', '=', $username)->first();
Config::set('database.connections.tenant.username', $tenant->db_username);
Config::set('database.connections.tenant.password', $tenant->db_password);
Config::set('database.connections.tenant.database', $tenant->db_database);
```

This will require to create 2 connections in your database.php file. (for instance app and tenant) and specify in your model which database to use (1 for the storing of tenants, 1 for the tenant specific database)

And probably create a route/script to create/update the tables. Not sure about migrations with multiple databases.

Comment: How do you get the connection instance after setting the Configuration?

Comment: You can just do: DB::connection('tenant') or specify the connection in your model: public static $connection = 'tentant';

Answer (score 4):

You can create dynamic DB connections in laravel with following syntax

```
Config::set('database.connections.key', array(
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'database'  => 'dbname',
    'username'  => 'dbuser',
    'password'  => 'dbpass',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
));
```

With that `DB::connection('key'); would just work.`

Answer (score 0):

I've recently encountered a similar problem, had to use different Databases for several models.

I've found the following to do the trick.

1. In app/config/database.php add a new connection MY_NEW_CONNECTION
2. For the new connection, set the database name to whatever
3. In your filters.php or routes.php or controller's __construct method add the following:

   $db = 'get your database name';
   Config::set('database.connections.MY_NEW_CONNECTION.database',$db);
   DB::setDefaultConnection('MY_NEW_CONNECTION');

Answer (score -3):

1) You can define multiple named connections in your database.php config file

```
'connections' => array(
    'tenant1' => array(
     ...
    ),
    'tenant2' => array(
     ...
    ),
```

Then you can choose which one to use with something like this.

```
$something = DB::connection('tenant1')->select(...);
```

2) This isn't a full solution as I think it will require some hacking on the core, but you can choose which connection to run a migration on. Maybe you could iterate through your list of tenants and run it on all of them.

```
Schema::connection('tenant1')->create('users', function($table)
```

3) Unfortunately, I don't think seeding supports multiple connections yet. You might have to roll your own seeding functionality.

Comment: There are 100's of tenants. And adding them all manually to database.php is not really ideal. That's why i asked on how to create a connection on the fly.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's possible. You could dynamically generate the connections array using information from your main database.

Comment: Also, you could possibly add/remove databases from the config file dynamically using the Config::set function.