# Creating the database on fly

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am working on laravel 4 app, In that i wan to allow the user to register for the app and when they register the app should allow a new empty database to the registered user,I am using mysql for backend I know  the following code to set the database connection

```
Config::set('database.connections', ConnectionArray);
```

And to set it as default

```
Config::set('database.default', ConnectionKey);
```

To connect another database manually i can use this way

```
'mysql' => array(
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'database'  => 'database', 
    'username'  => 'root',
    'password'  => '123456',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
),
'mysql_tenant1' => array(
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'database'  => 'tenant1',  
    'username'  => 'root',
    'password'  => '123456',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
),
```

But i want the app should create database dynamically...

Comment: This doesn't seem a good idea to have different databases for different users, what is the scenario ?

Comment: Actually i am working on SaaS app so in this every user will have one database and the all database details will be stored in main database...so when the user register to the app, The app should allocate the new empty database to the registered user...here i need to work with domain and sub-domain all...but the problem is to create the new database...

Comment: I understand you are building SaaS, but... Image you need to alter table for some reason, after half a year after service launch, having 1000 users. Yeah, you need to alter 1000 databases, instead of one. Just stick with relations and one database.

Comment: Anybody who jumps to the conclusion that a single database is one-size-fits-all hasn't done their homework. In the use case of 1,000 or 10,000 or 100,000 tenants, it's easier for multiple databases to scale horizontally than vertically (i.e., move dbs around on multiple servers versus throwing a lot of computing power at one massive database). There are other tech advantages to multiple db. There are also business reasons (i.e., segregation of data) for choosing multiple db over single db. Many articles have been written on the subject, and a single db is not necessarily the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating the Database itself will be relatively simple.  The complexity comes in associating those databases to users somehow, and then pulling those database names and using them in connections.  This should help:

In terms of overall strategy, consider creating a new repository with a few functions:

1. `RegisterUser()` - This registers the user with username/password.
2. `CreateDatabase($name , $user_id)` -  This should create your
   database and store it's name in a table, and then assign it to the User ID you created in Register User.

You can run raw SQL queries in Laravel with `DB::statement()` (i.e - ``DB::statement('create database' . $name);`, so stick that in your CreateDatabase function.  I tested this locally and it works just fine.

NOTE: You'll want to do some validation to make sure the database doesn't already exist, or your user is going to (obviously) get an error.

Then, you can pull the Database name from the table by User ID and create connections with it as described in the below SO!

[Laravel 4: Multiple Tenant Application, each tenant it's own database and one global database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14524181/laravel-4-multiple-tenant-application-each-tenant-its-own-database-and-one-gl)

One thing - when you make a change to your database structure, you're going to have to update each database individually.  Note that Artisan allows for this with the `--database="database_name"` option.

Comment: Another question - have you considered your backup and server migration strategy?  Among the selling points for SaaS is that the information is always available.  This means that if your Server (Server A) goes down, you'll need to have another server (Server B) available.  And then C, D, E and so forth.

The multi-database model may make it difficult to accomplish this strategy if you intend to have thousands and thousands of users.

Comment: This helped me a great deal. Thanks for the suggestion James Binford

Answer (score 0):

Just have a user_id field in whatever table(DB from what I think you're describing) you want, and use relationships to make it work, a whole bunch of fields in one table(or more than one table) may be FAR more efficient than what you think.

Comment: I understand your concept but it is SaaS app so i don't want to build it in only one database, So i want to know is there any method by which the app can create the new database on fly